# how to manage security with user added external css (like myspace)

Tags: css, security, xss

I've got a page which it has been requested I allow some user customization via CSS.

I'm happy to do this, but am trying to figure out how to make it secure. 
There aren't many stylesheets that will be applied to the page, but I had originally thought that if I just checked that the page was a css extension that I would be safe.

However, the research I have done shows that xss is easy to do through css. 
But i haven't been able to find any resouces on how to allow user generated external css to be included safely.

Does anybody have an suggestions or resources for this?

MySpace manages to do it, along with a few other sites, but I can't see how to ensure this will be secure.

I don't have any 'secure' user data on the page where the external css goes. But I do get a few variables for a search.

----------------additional data after sliky's response ----------------------

I am not planning on enabling every user to add an external css. However, the css variable can be set by special qualified users, and once that variable is availble, essentially anybody can set it as they please. The only method for getting that variable in use is to spread the URL themselves, so maybe I'm over concerned with the security, but I doubt it.

I can set it so that the page is not indexed with a external stylesheet, but am still concerned about how to maintain security for the end user.

I would have a link on my site where it would be 
http://mysite.com/page?useracct=12343&extcss=http://location/of/css.css

I set-up the useracct, so only where the users I allow to enable the different css have links created for their pages. On my site, I would link to that users account with the css page.

So somebody can't just come along and say 
http://mysite.com/page?extcss=http://new/dangerous/css.css

However, they could create the link
http://mysite.com/page?useracct=12343&extcss=http://new/dangerous/css.css
The only way somebody would get to that page would be if that person who created the dangerous css forwarded that link along.

I guess if I hashed and salted the extcss, it could be more secure. Maybe that is the best way to go?

Answer (score 4):

Use a language that has a CSS library, or write a parser to build an AST-like structure from the CSS and then check for dodgy stuff.

This might be harder than it sounds, things like div sizes (engulfing the entire page), floating and z-orders will be tricky to manage and you may have to have bounds on the values you can provide.

*a nice idea*

Create an XML based theming schema that can be translated to CSS. Allow users to upload images+XML to generate a theme.

XML is simpler to control.

[PHP CSS Parser](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/1289.html), [Python CSS parsing](http://renesd.blogspot.com/2007/01/python-css-parsing.html)

**Good Luck**

Comment: very informative response Aiden, and thanks for the link on the css parser.  I don't think the user uploaded xml + images is what they are really looking for. Just trying to get some simple styles applied, and for positioning, i always include my stylesheet after, so that handles any floating/z-index etc. issues as all element positioning is set post the user stuff. It's mostly some minor-sizing, colors & background images they can adjust.

With the 'this might be harder than it sounds' and bolded 'Good Luck' are you suggesting that maybe I shouldn't be doing this?

Comment: Not atall, just remember that things like !important and other obscure things can bite you in the bum if you let users upload css (or any content for that matter). Make it almost mathematical ... work out the permutations of all available syntax you want to block and test that it works. Depends on how important sanitizing the input is ... if it is a small site for friends, you can relax a bit :) Go for it I say!

Answer (score 2):

While effectively having your own language for allowing the addition of CSS may seem good, you may still inevitably end up with the same problems as letting them just write anything (say loading external files, etc) and be in a world of hurt.

A better model, from a security point of view, is think over exactly what they will want to customise and let them only edit those things.

So you may provide abilities to set:

- Background colours
- Fonts
- Images for various things
- Etc

Twitter (last time I used it anyway) had a nice method for doing this, and the result is also that the site is customisable, yet maintains a standard look, which, IMHO, is great.

Comment: though i agree with you silky, the task of creating a design management system like twitter is rather daunting. I'd only be providing capabilities to a few users, who would be making design and layout improvements better than I can do. My security concern is that once I provide the ability for these special users to add a css, essentially anybody can use the variable to set their own css. Though they would need to send on that URL they created for it to proliferate. I can set no-index for when the external css is set, but still have concerns about what I'm getting myself in to.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to do what twitter does. Just only allow specific things (as I said) and if you want a cool interface for selection, jQuery will provide what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that CSS can execute arbitrary JS.  See

- http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CssAllowsArbitraryCodeExecution
- http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CssImportsAllowUnsanitizedCodeExecution
- http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/HistoryMining

If you need a flexible CSS parser and sanitizer, you can take a look at [CssValidator](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/plugin/CssValidator.java) and its associated tests show some of what it does: [CssValidatorTest](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/caja/plugin/CssValidatorTest.java)